# Is there any algebraic structure equipped with multi-valued map(s)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

A group is a non-empty set $G$ with a map $m: G \times G \mapsto G$ where the map is associative, has an identity element and has an inverse element for all $ g \in G$.

Similarly in other algebraic structures, we equip them with one or more mapping that are always single-valued i.e. the map involved is always like the following: $m: S_1 \times S_2\times \ldots \times S_n \mapsto S_a$.

Why is it never like the following: $m: (S_1 \times S_2) \mapsto (S_1 \times S_2)$ or like $m: (S_1 \times S_2\times \ldots \times S_n) \mapsto (S_1 \times S_2\times \ldots \times S_n)$

Is there any algebraic structure with such type of map?

PS: I am confused about whether I should use the word map here. Cause almost everywhere the word map is used to denote a single-valued assignment. While my interest here is multiple-valued assignment.

Comment: Hopf algebras have comultiplications which are maps of the ilk $H \to H \otimes H$.  This is kind of what you're looking for.

Comment: More generally, a Hopf algebra is an example of a comonoid, which is a structure with a comultiplication which is coassociative and counital.

Comment: @Randall, Yes, from a quick google search, it seems like that is what I was looking for! But I am thinking about whether there is some kind of algebraic structures using that map and what the names of those structures are

Comment: The name of those structures are Hopf algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Mapping to multiple elements":** Yes, these structures are called "hyper" and the concept of hypergroups (careful: nowadays the definition is a bit different) was first introduced by Krasner in 1934 if I recall correctly. The main difference is a the use of $n$-ary hypermaps, which are maps of the form $S^n \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(S) \setminus \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace$. Choosing multiple values is formalized by mapping to the subset of the wanted multiple values.

This is for example used to produce one model of $\mathbb{F}_1$-geometry by doing algebraic geometry with respect to hyperrings. Let me actually (without mentioning the precise definition) give an example of a hyperring (actually a hyperfield):

The so called Krasner hyperfield $\mathbb{K} = \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ is given by setting $1 + 1 = \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ and using the addition and multiplication from $\mathbb{F}_2$ otherwise. This hyperfield captures the arithmetic of a $0$-element with non-zero elements in the following sense:
The sum of $0$ and $0$ is $0$ and the sum of a $0$-element and non-zero elements: is non-zero while the sum of two non-zero elements could be either $0$ or something non-zero, which is why we want it to be the set $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$.